# npm doesn't compile changes made on production server

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, compilation

I have a laravel application deployed on a shared hosting server. I managed to deploy the app, install all the composer/node dependencies and it all runs with no error. I'm trying to make some minor changes on one of my components, but for some reason after the npm run dev(production) everything seems to be compilled with no error, but the actual application in the browser does not reflect the changes. I tried to clear all the caches in the app and in the browsers I'm using. I tried also to run 'npm run watch'. I replaced files, also I replaced the whole folder. If I remove something npm does display the error about the missing files, but the changes are not compiled. I've been googling now for 2 hours,but I cannot find anything useful . Any idea is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) / [Github](https://github.com/) for deployment? Easiest solution would be to `npm run prod` locally and then push to your remote server, I think.

Comment: This really does sound like a cache issue... With your dev tools open, right click on the refresh button and do a clear cache and hard reload.

Comment: I did open the page on other devices and it returns the same old version of the page. It's definitely not cached. I used cpanel for deployment.

Comment: I discovered something interesting. visiting the page using the full https link return the changes partly. The latest compiled changes still not taking action, but at least I achieved some updates. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Laravel Mix's `.version()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting) could help in cache busting. Don't forget to use `mix('path')` instead of `asset('path')` in your blade files